# Set TCP_QUICKACK and TCP_NODELAY

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

If you set the TCP_QUICKACK setting on every call on the socket, having previously set TCP_NODELAY, will the QUICKACK option overwrite the NODELAY call?

On connect:

```
int i = 1;
setsockopt( iSock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void *)&i, sizeof(i));
```

On each write:

```
int i = 1;
setsockopt( iSock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_QUICKACK, (void *)&i, sizeof(i));
```

Will the call to TCP_QUICKACK null the previous call to TCP_NODELAY?

Comment: What happened when you did this, and monitored the behavior using something like Wireshark?

Comment: Using getsockopt, I have verified that the TCP_QUICKACK does not overwrite TCP_NODELAY.

Comment: Why do you do this each write? An ACK is sent for every packet received, so TCP_QUICKACK should be set after every recv or am I missing something

Comment: Why do you need both quickack and nodelay? Setting nodelay should usually do the trick.

Comment: @lxgr TCP_QUICKACK affects receivers; TCP_NODELAY affects senders. If you do not have control over both endpoints, you may need to set both settings in order to get the desired network performance.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There's no direct relationship between those two options, they are just for different purposes.

**TCP_NODELAY** is intended to disable/enable segment buffering so data can be sent out to peer as quickly as possible, so this is typically used to improve network utilisation. **TCP_QUICKACK** is used to send out acknowledgements as early as possible than delayed under some protocol level exchanging, and it's not stable/permanent, subsequent TCP transactions (which may happen under the hood) can disregard this option depending on actual protocol level processing or any actual disagreements between user setting and stack behaviour.

**NOTE** `TCP_NODELAY` is portable while `TCP_QUICKACK` is not (only works under Linux 2.4.4+).

Answer (score 16):

Use TCP_QUICKACK, not TCP_NODELAY

> Turning on TCP_NODELAY has similar effects, but can make throughput
>   worse for small writes. If you write a loop which sends just a few
>   bytes (worst case, one byte) to a socket with "write()", and the Nagle
>   algorithm is disabled with TCP_NODELAY, each write becomes one IP
>   packet. This increases traffic by a factor of 40, with IP and TCP
>   headers for each payload. Tinygram prevention won't let you send a
>   second packet if you have one in flight, unless you have enough data
>   to fill the maximum sized packet. It accumulates bytes for one round
>   trip time, then sends everything in the queue. That's almost always
>   what you want. If you have TCP_NODELAY set, you need to be much more
>   aware of buffering and flushing issues. None of this matters for bulk
>   one-way transfers, which is most HTTP today. (I've never looked at the
>   impact of this on the SSL handshake, where it might matter.) Short
>   version: set TCP_QUICKACK. If you find a case where that makes things
>   worse, let me know. John Nagle

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10608356

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer**

- To disable Nagle's buffering algorithm, use the TCP_NODELAY socket option.
- To disable Delayed ACKs, use the TCP_QUICKACK socket option.

**Details**

- Nagle's algorithm

  - Nagle's algorithm, named after its creator John Nagle, is one mechanism for improving TCP efficiency by reducing the number of small packets sent over the network.
  - The goal was to prevent a node from transmitting many small packets if the application delivers data to the socket rather slowly.
  - If a process is causing many small packets to be transmitted, it may be creating undue network congestion. This is especially true if the payload of a packet is smaller than the TCP header data.
- Delayed ACK

  - TCP delayed acknowledgment or Delayed ACK is another technique used by some implementations of the TCP in an effort to improve network performance and reduce congestion.
  - Delayed ACK was invented to reduce the number of ACKs required to acknowledge the segments and reduce the protocol overhead.
  - Delayed ACK means TCP doesn't immediately acknowledge every single received TCP segment. Several ACK responses may be combined together into a single response, reducing protocol overhead.
- Nagle's Algorithm and Delayed ACK Do Not Play Well Together in a TCP/IP Network

  - Delayed ACK tries to send more data per segment if it can. But part of Nagle's algorithm depends on an ACK to send data.
  - Nagle's algorithm and Delayed ACKs together create a problem because Delayed ACKs are waiting around to send the ACK while Nagle's is waiting around to receive the ACK
  - [Sample](https://jvns.ca/blog/2015/11/21/why-you-should-understand-a-little-about-tcp/)

    ```
    client: hi! Here’s the first packet
    server: <silence, waiting for the second packet, well I’ll ack eventually>
    client: <silence, well I’m waiting for an ACK, maybe there’s network congestion>
    server: Ok I am bored. Here’s an ack
    client: Great, here’s the second packet!
    server: Sweet. we’re done here
    ```

    - The client is doing it because of Nagle’s algorithm, and the server is because of delayed ACKs.
- How can I resolve the issues caused by Nagle's algorithm and Delayed ACKs

  - Enable TCP_NODELAY to disable Nagle's algorithm via global socket options on the servers
  - Make profile tweaks on proxy servers and Load Balancers: This is especially relevant if you're running applications or environments that only sometimes have highly interactive traffic and chatty protocols. By dynamically switching Nagle's Algorithm and TCP_NODELAY on and off at the load balancer level, you can keep even highly heterogeneous traffic mixes running optimally.
  - Reduce the Delayed ACK timer on your servers and load balancers. Sometimes, this kind of optimization is handled in software, at the application level, but when that's not the case, you may still be able to dynamically manage the ACK timer at the server or load balancer level.
  - As you're making these changes, keep careful watch on your network traffic and see how each tweak impacts congestion.

For more details please refer to [this](https://www.extrahop.com/company/blog/2016/tcp-nodelay-nagle-quickack-best-practices/)

Answer (score 5):

`TCP_QUICKACK` and `TCP_NODELAY` affect different operations in TCP. The [`tcp(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/tcp.7.html) man page describes which socket options for TCP interfere with each other, e.g. `TCP_CORK` and `TCP_NODELAY`.