# Remote Websocket server performance

Tags: performance, phpwebsocket

I have created a php websocket server, and a php websocket client, the websocket client communicate with the server using JSON format, each message means an operation to handle by the websocket server.
when running both the client and the server in localhost I can reach about **35 operations/sconds**, and the same results when running both client and websocket server on the production server, but running client in locahost (my machine) with production websocket server (remote) that only results in **5 operations/seconds**.

What could be the reason behind that bad performance when using remote websocket server?

Comment: Details are missing: is the operation compute bound, throughput bound or latency bound? I expect the operation to be latency bound due to websocket wich AFAIK are based on TCP. TCP uses the [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) that can slow down the operations (the handshake can be a bit slow too). If your server is fully async and the client is not bound by the RTT latency, then it should be much faster unless the computation is expensive or sent data are huge (certainly not). 35 operations/seconds is pretty bad already...

Comment: The operation is latency bound, and the client is bound by the RTT latency (send first operation details wait for server response then send next operation details...),
I do really confused what happens when passing by internet bridge! because running both client and server on the same machine works perfectly.

Comment: AFAIK, OS does optimizations when processes are on the same machine not to use the NIC so it makes sense to get much faster results. The TCP delay may be adapted by the OS by default too. All of that can be configured (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286592/set-tcp-quickack-and-tcp-nodelay)). UDP communications does not pay such (high) overhead so they are much faster for low latency but they are not used for WebSocket (because UDP datagrams can be lost, there is no connected mode and some other issues).

Comment: Whatever the method used to communicate and the socket configuration, keep in mind that the application should limit the number of ping-pong operations as people can live far away with a huge latency, have a poor ISP or just a poor networking accesses (eg. edge, 3G, old WiFi). Not to mention the latency will likely not be better in the future while the throughput is still increasing in most countries. Related: https://gist.github.com/hellerbarde/2843375

Comment: I need to still in connected mode so UDP communications is not favorable in my situation, and you're right it could be due to multiple factors such as networking access..., thank you very much @Jérôme Richard for this helpful explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by changing websocket client app logic (sending messages asynchronously instead of synchronously), by using that approach we have increased the score to more than 100 operations/s.
Credits to [Jérôme Richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12939557/j%C3%A9r%C3%B4me-richard) (See the question comments)